# How to change the image resource for another language?

Tags: java, android, drawable

I'm developing an app that presents pictures. Each picture shows German text in it. Surely I also want to release my app in other countries than Germany.  To do that, I have to change the pics to the specific language.

```
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    i++;

    if (i == 1) {
        //Your 2 Image
        testanzeige.setImageResource(R.drawable.v1);

    } else if (i == 2) {
        //Your 3 Image
        testanzeige.setImageResource(R.drawable.v2);
      }
});
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I don't see any string?

Comment: sorry, i used a completely wrong title. edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just put your resources in drawable folder with the country name like

```
res/drawable-ja/ //for japan
```

rest android will pick automatically according to region.Images name should be same in all folder.

Comment: thanks a lot!! what if I, for example, only create  the folder en: will it always take the pictures from there, if the language on the phone is english? I mean, does it mater if the user is in England or USA?

Comment: Interesting this needs to be checked but always make sure you have image in res/drawable/ folder or your application will not load in my knowledge it will take pictures from the en folder for more go through this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html this help you a lot for localisation support.

Answer (score 0):

you can create the images for different locale and place it in the different locale folder (image name should be same -  says img_xyz)

now when you refer R.drawable.img_xyz Android automatically will  pick the images based on the device locale settings